# Fantasy novel where guy fights with a cloak on his back

Tags: story-identification, novel

There was a novel I read back in the 90s (I’m pretty sure) about a guy who fought using a weighted cloak or cape. There’s very little I remember about it beyond that. He didn’t take the cloak off in the cloak-and-dagger style, but rather used it kind of like a whip from his back and shoulders. Anyone ever heard of it?

Comment: If you haven't already, can I suggest you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details

Comment: This sounds like The Shattered World by Michael Reaves. Some google searching reveals that one character is a cape/cloak fighter who has blades woven into his cloak. The book was published in 1985.

https://www.amazon.com/Shattered-World-Michael-Reaves/dp/0671559516

Comment: Thanks @just_happen_to_know I'm buying the book now and will update if it's what I'm looking for

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108472/looking-for-title-and-author-fantasy-shapeshifting-thief-sorceress

Comment: @just_happen_to_know: If you put your suggestion as an answer rather than just as a comment, then he can choose it as correct if it turns out to be right, and you will get points for it.

Comment: @just_happen_to_know appears to be correct, btw. Happy to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just_happen_to_know comes back, I'll yield the answer, but *[The Shattered World](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1844103.The_Shattered_World)* by Michael Reaves was identified in the comments and confirmed there was well.

> A thousand years ago, the world was broken in a great cataclysm; now people live on the fragments, flying between them in ships made of the skin & bone of dragons. The book follows the interweaving stories of a thief, a couple of wizards, and various others as events are set in motion that will take them on perilous journeys to the far reaches of the world with far-reaching consequences.

The "cloakfighter" is named Kan Konar.

There's a sequel with some of the characters including Kan Konar called [The Burning Realm](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1867041.The_Burning_Realm).